# JavaScript: Get the control name which caused postback [client-side]

Tags: javascript

How can I get the control name which caused postback [in an ASPX webform] from the client-side (JavaScript)?

Note that I am registering a script on the Page_Load() event of the webform using ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(...).

Any help is appreciated!